# retrieve record my xcdatamodel and filter them

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

sorry for my english, but I need to filter my table by my third data (I have added this data after creating my tabel). In my log I watched my app don't retrieve myThirdData, but if I log my entity attributes. There is myThirdData too. This is my log:

```
"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x8dbc390>), name myFirstData, isOptional
 1, isTransient 0, entity Targhe, renamingIdentifier dataIns,
 validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier
 (null)\n userInfo {\n    \"com.apple.syncservices.Syncable\" = NO;\n},
 attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue
 (null)",
     "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x8dbc280>), name mySecondData, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Targhe, renamingIdentifier targa,
 validation predicates (\n    \"length <= 7\"\n), warnings (\n   
 1660\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700
 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)" 
 "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x8dbc010>), name myThirdData, isOptional
 0, isTransient 1, entity Targhe, renamingIdentifier utente, validation
 predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo
 {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString,
 defaultValue (null)" ) [...] 2015-01-06 09:56:40.211
 myProject[581:60b] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT,
 t0.ZMYFIRSTDATA, t0.ZMYSECONDDATA FROM ZMYENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN 
 (?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZMYFIRSTDATA DESC LIMIT 20
```

When I add my predicate, I have an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath myThirdData not found in
 entity <NSSQLEntity MyEntity id=1>'
```

This is my predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myThirdData = %@", myThirdDataVar];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self = %@", myThirdDataVar];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; try like this if that is going to an string

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.attributeName = %@", myThirdDataVar]; [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];  for this will be an object case  is solved ???

Comment: Have you set `myThirdData` attribute to transient?

Comment: Wain, yes my attribute is transient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transient attributes don't exist in the data store so you can't use them in predicates run on the MOC. Either you need to make the attribute non-transient or you will need to do a fetch and then filter the results (though after the fetch the transients will all be null).